# How to show some columns as selected and some are unselected in PrimeNg Multiselect component

Tags: angular, primeng

How to show some columns as selected and some are unselected inside primeng multiselect.

```
  this.cols = [
{ field: 'A', label: 'A', display: true },
{ field: 'B', label: 'B', display:false },
{ field: 'C', label: 'C', display: false },
]

this.selectedColumns(cols)

selectedColumns(selectedColumns: any) {
    this._selectedColumns = selectedColumns;
    this._selectedColumns.sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key);
  }





<p-multiSelect id="EventTypeSelection" 
        [options]="cols"
        [(ngModel)]="_selectedColumns"
         optionLabel="header"
        (onChange)="userSelection($event)"
        defaultLabel="Column Options" 
       >
     </p-multiSelect>
```

It show all selected by default I need to show only whose property display is true only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the selection whose display property is true then you should filter out the selectedColumns based on the display property.

```
selectedColumns(selectedColumns: any) {
    this._selectedColumns = selectedColumns.filter(row=>row.display);
    this._selectedColumns.sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key);
  }
```